# Long text in tipsy tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jquery-tooltip, tipsy

I'm happily using tipsy for my d3.js graphs, but now I noticed that tipsy is cutting off text if it's too long.

For instance the line containing the word *CALCULATOR* is cut off:

[image: Text of tooltip is cut off]

Is there a way to extend the width of the tooltip or autosize it according to the longest line of the tooltip text (I didn't find anything in the docs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own tooltips module for D3 (see below). It uses [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).
I use it like this:

```
define('myD3module',
// This module depends on the following modules
['tooltips', 'd3'], 
    function (tooltips, d3){

// Code omitted...

var node = svg.selectAll('g.node');
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
.on('mouseover', onMouseOver)                  
.on('mouseout', onMouseOut);

// Code omitted...

var onMouseOver = function(d){
       tooltips.showTooltip(d, getTooltipText);
};

var onMouseOut = function(d){
        tooltips.hideTooltip(d);
};

// Code omitted...
var getTooltipText = function(d){
    var tipText = '';
    var name = d.name;
    if(typeof name != 'undefined'){
        tipText += 'Name = ' + name + '<br>';
    }
    return tipText;
};
```

This is the module.

```
// This module shows tooltips near the user's cursor. The text of the tooltip must be provided by the consumer of this module. This module can be used with require.js.
define('tooltips',
// Required modules:
['d3','jquery'],
function (d3, $){

    // Contains the tooltip. This div will be repositioned as needed.
    var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')   
                    .attr('class', 'tooltip')               
                    .style('opacity', 0);

    // This CSS styles the tooltip
    var css = './config/tooltip.css';
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = css;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);

    var hideTooltip = function (d) {       
            tooltip.style('opacity', 0);   
        },

        /** Show the tooltip. The text is defined by a function and the element the mouse cursor is placed on. */
        showTooltip = function (elem, getTooltipText){      
            tooltip.style('opacity', 0.9);      
            var text = getTooltipText(elem);
            var tipWidth = getTooltipWidth(text);
            // Draw the tips below the mouse cursor
            var tipYpos = d3.event.pageY + 20;
            tooltip.html(text)  
                // The tooltip is centered below the cursor
                .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - tipWidth/2) + 'px')     
                .style('top', tipYpos + 'px')
                .style('width', tipWidth + 'px')
                .style('height', getTooltipHeight(text) + 'px');
        },

        /**
         * The tooltip spans all the text's lines vertically.
         */
         getTooltipHeight = function (text) {

            var totalHeight = 0;
            var lines = text.split('<br>');
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
                var line = $.trim(lines[i]);
                // Ignore empty strings
                if(line.length > 0){
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = line;
                    $('body').append(span);
                    totalHeight +=  $(span).height();
                    $(span).remove();
                }
            }
            return totalHeight;
        },

        /*
         * The width of the tooltip is the width of the longest line in the tooltip text
         */
        getTooltipWidth = function (text){

            var lines = text.split('<br>');
            // Append a dummy span containing the current line to the DOM. The browser calculates the width of that span
            var maxWidth = d3.max(lines, function(line) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = line;
                    $('body').append(span);
                    var spanWidth = $(span).width();
                    $(span).remove();
                    return spanWidth; 
                    });
            return maxWidth;
        };

        // These functions are public
        return {
            showTooltip: showTooltip,
            hideTooltip: hideTooltip
        };
    }
);
```

This is the tooltip.css:

```
.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;           
    text-align: center;           
    font: 12px sans-serif;        
    background-color: rgb(95,230,245);   
    border-radius: 2px;           
    pointer-events: none;         
}
```